# Windows 7 VBS generated batch file will not start

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, batch-file

I'm using VBS to build a batch file for installing updates.  To make sure it works the way I expected it to, I built this little test script, however the generated batch file errors out on launch with an unrecognized character, no matter what the first character is.  VBS script:

```
option explicit

Dim objFSO, objFile, objWShell

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Test.bat", 2, True)
Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objFile.Write("@echo off" & vbCrLf & "echo " & chr(34) & "this is a test" & chr(34) & vbCrLf & "echo " & chr(34) & "This is only a test" & chr(34) & vbCrLf & "timeout /t 5")
Set objFile = Nothing

objWShell.Run "Test.bat"

wscript.quit
```

Running the script creates and instantly closes the window the bat runs in, but launching the generated bat from a command line yields that the first command being passed (in this case @echo off, but have tried with others) includes an extra character at the beginning, and only passes that character (which appears as a solid square, presumably one windows doesn't know) and the first character of the first command in the batch file.  Thus I get something similar to '▬@ is not a recognized internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Selecting "Show all characters" in npp when viewing both the batch file and the generating script shows no extra characters and all line breaks in both are crlf.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the last parameter of CreateTextFile to False makes the file ASCII and it then runs properly. (You're currently saving it as Unicode which doesn't usually play nice with command prompt)

Comment: I see.  Looking it up I was feeding it arguments as if it was the OpenTextFile method.  Thanks!